# How to approach summing up individual sets of columns per id in postgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql, facebook-graph-api

**Task: I need to sum up relevant values from a json for a specific id. How can I accomplish this in postgreSQL?**

I receive post insights from Facebook's Graph API and it contains a cell with a json listing countries with their two letter abbreviation and the corresponding watchtime in ms from that country.

| post_id | date | watchtime_per_country |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 107_[pageID] | 2022-09-01 | ** see json below ** |

The second part is a table that contains the relevant countries for each [page_id]

| page_id | target country |
| --- | --- |
| P01 | Germany (DE) |
| P01 | Italy (IT) |
| P02 | Mozambique (MZ) |
| P02 | Colombia (CO) |

Now I would like to get the sum of
Germany (DE): 162 and Japan (JP): 24 --> 186 for P01
Mozambique (MZ): 3 and 6 --> 9 for P02

So far I have unnested the json and unpacked all possible +-250 country values into own columns but I am not sure whether this is a good approach. After that I am not sure how to build those sums in a flexible efficient way. Or whether it is possible at all in postgreSQL.
Does anyone have an idea?

**** json ****
{"Brazil (BR)": 9210, "Germany (DE)": 162, "Portugal (PT)": 68, "Japan (JP)": 24, "United States (US)": 17, "Italy (IT)": 13, "France (FR)": 9, "United Kingdom (GB)": 8, "Netherlands (NL)": 6, "Belgium (BE)": 6, "Colombia (CO)": 6, "Austria (AT)": 5, "Sweden (SE)": 4, "Canada (CA)": 4, "Argentina (AR)": 3, "Mozambique (MZ)": 3, "Angola (AO)": 3, "Switzerland (CH)": 2, "Saudi Arabia (SA)": 2, "New Zealand (NZ)": 2, "Norway (NO)": 2, "Indonesia (ID)": 2, "Denmark (DK)": 2, "United Arab Emirates (AE)": 2, "Russia (RU)": 2, "Spain (ES)": 1, "China (CN)": 1, "Israel (IL)": 1, "Chile (CL)": 0, "Bulgaria (BG)": 0, "Australia (AU)": 0, "Cape Verde (CV)": 0, "Ireland (IE)": 0, "Egypt (EG)": 0, "Luxembourg (LU)": 0, "Bolivia (BO)": 0, "Paraguay (PY)": 0, "Uruguay (UY)": 0, "Czech Republic (CZ)": 0, "Hungary (HU)": 0, "Finland (FI)": 0, "Algeria (DZ)": 0, "Peru (PE)": 0, "Mexico (MX)": 0, "Guinea-Bissau (GW)": 0}

Comment: Now, that I thought a bit.. it might be better to unpack the values into one column with the code next to it, instead of a column for each value..

Answer (score 0):

You have a couple ways you can go. If you will do little the post insights then you can get page sums directly processing the JSON.
Your later comment indicates there may be more. Unpacking the JSON into a single table is the way to go; it is data normalization.
One very slight correction. The 2 character is not a MS coding for the country. It is the [ISO-3166](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_ISO_3166_country_codes#Current_ISO_3166_country_codes) alpha-2 code (defined in ISO-3166-1) (yes MS uses it).  
Either way the first step is to extract the keys from the JSON then use those keys to extract the Values. Then JOIN the `relevant_countries` table on the `alpha2` code.

```
with work_insights (jkey,country_watchtime) as   
           ( select json_object_keys(country_watchtime), country_watchtime
               from insights_data_stage 
           ) 
   , watch_insights(cntry, alpha2, watchtime) as 
           ( select trim(replace(substring(jkey, '^.*\('),'(','')) 
                  , upper(trim(replace(replace(substring(jkey, '\(.*\)'),'(',''),')','')) ) 
                  , (country_watchtime->> jkey)::numeric 
               from work_insights
           ) 
   , relevant_codes (page_id, alpha2) as 
          ( select page_id, substring(substring(target_country, '\(..\)'),2,2) alpha2
              from relevant_countries
          )       
select rc.page_id,  sum(watchtime) watchtime 
  from relevant_codes  rc
  join watch_insights  wi
    on (wi.alpha2 = rc.alpha2) 
 where rc.page_id in ('P01','P02') 
 group by rc.page_id
 order by rc.page_id;
```

For the normalization process you need a country table (as you already said you have) and another table for the normalized insights data. Populating begins the same
parsing as above, but developing columns for each value. Once created you JOIN this table with `relevant_countries`. (See [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/KkkqZrKi) containing both). Note: I normalized the `relevant_countries` table.

```
select rc.page_id, sum(pi.watchtime) watchtime 
  from post_insights       pi
  join relevant_countries_rev  rc on (rc.alpha2 = pi.alpha2) 
 group by rc.page_id
 order by rc.page_id;
```

**Update:** The results for P01 do not match your expected results. Your expectations indicate to sum Germany and Japan, but your `relevant_countries` table indicates Germany and Italy.